# How can i get sum of each column fron 2D Array and save it to 1D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

with first function i fill 5x5 array with 0 (means that users aren't friends, or 1 that mean they are friends.
second function calculate friends of each user.
third function calculate and return common friends between users.
and i have problem with last fucntion, it have to calculate friends of each user and save it in 1D array, and then bubble short the array.

can anyone help me to find out what is wrong with the last function

friendship array is

```
01100
10111
11010
01100
01000
```

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* function declaration */
void loadMatrix (int **F, int size);
int findFriends (int **F, int size, int user);
int commonFriends (int **F, int size, int user1, int user2);
void sortUsers (int **F, int size, int *S);

int main()
{
    int **matrixF; /* friendship array */
    int *matrixS;  /* sum of each user array */
    int num_users; /* users number */
    int i, j;

    printf("Give number of users: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_users);

    /* allocate memory for array */
    matrixF = (int **) malloc(num_users * sizeof(int *));
    if (!matrixF)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_users; ++i)
    {
        matrixF[i] = (int *) malloc(num_users * sizeof(int));
        if (!matrixF[i])
        {
            printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    loadMatrix(matrixF, num_users);


    for (i=0; i<num_users; ++i)
    {
        printf("Number of friends of user %d: %d\n", i, findFriends(matrixF, num_users, i));
    }

    /* common friends */
    for (i=0; i<num_users; ++i)
    {
        for (j=0; j<i; ++j)
        {
            printf("Number of common friends of %d and %d: %d\n", i, j,  commonFriends(matrixF, num_users, i, j));
        }
    }

    matrixS = (int *)malloc(num_users * sizeof(int));
    if (!matrixS)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sortUsers(matrixF, num_users, matrixS);

    /* bubble short */
    for (i=0; i<num_users; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d friends.\n", matrixS[i]);
    }

    return 0;        
}

void loadMatrix (int **F, int size)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        for (j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            do
            {
                printf(" user%d is friend with user%d: ", i, j);
                scanf("%d", &F[i][j]);
                if ((F[i][j]<0) || (F[i][j]>1 )) printf("H timi prepei einai 0 i 1 . ");
            }
            while ((F[i][j]<0) || (F[i][j]>1));  /*please enter 0 or 1*/
        }
}


int findFriends (int **F, int size, int user) {

    int  j;
    int sum=0;

    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        sum+=F[user][j];
    }
    return (sum);
}


int commonFriends (int **F, int size, int user1, int user2) {

    int j;
    int counter=0;

    for (j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if ((F[user1][j]==1)&&(F[user2][j]==1))
            counter++;
    }
    return (counter);
    system("pause");
}

void sortUsers (int **F, int size, int *S)
{
    int  i, j, temp;
    int sum=0;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<size; j++)
            sum+=F[i][j];
    }
    S[i]=sum;

    printf("%d\t", S[i]);
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        S[i]=sum;
    }

    for (i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<size-1; j++)
        {
            if (S[j]>S[j+1])
            {
                temp = S[j];
                S[j] = S[j+1];
                S[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For one, your indexing is out of bounds. `S[i] = sum` is done when` i == num_users`. But `S` was only allocated to be `num_users` wide, so `0...(num_users-1)` is the allowable index range. This was considerably less-obvious with your original posting prior to editing, where the poor indentation and block-formatting were doing a find job of hiding it. Anyone that tells you good code-formatting is a luxury is a liar; consider it mandatory. You also never reset `sum` between iterations of the outer loop in the same area of code.

Comment: sorry but my english is bad.
i'm new in C and it's my second C program, the program is code templete and i just need to fill the functions.
i know that in last fuction is totale wrong but i tried many things

Answer (score 0):

i just find out the answer

```
void sortUsers (int **F, int size, int *S) {

int  i, j, temp, user;
int sum;  

for (i=0; i<size; i++){
   sum=0;
   for (j=0; j<size; j++)
   S[i]=(sum+=F[i][j]);

  }

   for (i=0; i<size; i++)
   printf("%d\t", S[i]);






  for (i=1; i<size; i++) {
  for (j=0; j<size-1; j++) {
     if (S[j]>S[j+1]) {
        temp = S[j];
        S[j] = S[j+1];
        S[j+1] = temp;
     }
  }
  }



  system("pause");


 }
```